# Transition Matrix from Pandas Dataframe That Has Two Periods in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I have a dataset that shows the customer's payment information for their dept.
Each customer have two periods of data.

```
CUST_ID PERIOD  Delinquency Value
100729    1              1
100729    2              3
100888    1              2
100888    2              1
137300    1              0
137300    2              1
```

I need to compute the transition ratios between delinquency values from period 1 to period 2, and create a table that stores this matrix

```
Expected output is:

    0   1   2   3
0   0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0   1
2   0   1   0   0
3   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: What would be the exact expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
tmp = df.pivot(index='CUST_ID', columns='PERIOD', values='Delinquency Value')
M = df['Delinquency Value'].max()+1

out = (pd.crosstab(tmp[1], tmp[2])
         .reindex(index=range(M), columns=range(M), fill_value=0)
       )

print(out.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  0  1  0  0
1  0  0  0  1
2  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks, edited the question and added expected output

Comment: It shows the transitions from period1 to period2..

Comment: Lovely!!! very thanks for your answer. What would be the logic be if I want to calculate percentage instead of count?
for example %33 for [0-1], %33 for  [1-3] and %33 for [2-1]

Comment: check the `normalize` option of `crosstab` ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot @mozway, you really helped me a lot.

Just as a last question, I have another column its called 'Amount' and it holds the amount of the payment.

I would like to find sum off these amounts in the matrix. I have seen aggfunc = 'sum' idea in crosstab but i couldn't make it work. any idea?

Comment: You have to pass the values explicitly with `values=...` if you use `aggfunc`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252786/discussion-between-burak-and-mozway).